# Dockerizing flask-sockerio app with nginx + gunicorn + postgres "Application object must be callable."

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have a flask application that I want to host on my VPS. I already have a domain name that is pointed to the VPS's IP.

My project structure is like this:

```
+-nginx
|   \nginx.conf
+-main.py
+-models.py
+-wsgi.py
+-requirements.txt
+-Dockerfile
+-docker-compose.yml
```

nginx\nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    }
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.3
WORKDIR /
COPY . /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -k gevent -w 1 wsgi:socket_
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        environment:
            - FLASK_APP=main.py
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - postgres

    postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
            - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
        volumes:
            - flask_polls_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=mymaiil
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=mypass
            - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
        ports:
            - 15432:80
        volumes:
            - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
        depends_on:
            - postgres

    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.19-alpine
        ports:
            - 1337:80
        depends_on:
            - web


volumes:
    flask_polls_data:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
```

wsgi.py:

```py
from main import app, socket_

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket_.run(app, debug=False)
```

The URI for the database is in `.env`:

```
URI=postgresql://myuser:mypassword@postgres:5432/mydb
```

I set the app config for URI like:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("URI", None)
```

I get this error when I run `docker-compose up --build`

> web_1       | Application object must be callable.

models.py:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User name: {self.name}>"
```

And this is main.py:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from models import *

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socket_ = SocketIO(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("URI", None)

db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
sess: Session = db.session  # type: ignore

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    return {
        "hello": "world"
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_.run(app)
```

This is what I see in the console:

```
Attaching to test_postgres_1, test_pgadmin_1, test_web_1, test_nginx_1
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.043 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.045 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.045 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.049 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.058 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-10 09:05:55 UTC
postgres_1  | 2022-09-10 09:06:25.073 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:27 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
web_1       | /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
web_1       |   warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
web_1       | Application object must be callable.
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:30 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:30 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_1       | [2022-09-10 09:06:30 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
test_web_1 exited with code 4
```

If I go to to VPS IP I get the default nginx page where it tells me further configuration is required. If I go to domain I get `502 Bad Gateway`.

Comment: Nothing you show here references the host name `postgres` at all.  Where does it come from and how is it used?  Is any of the Nginx configuration required to reproduce the issue, or do you see this if you reduce the configuration to just the `web` and `postgres` containers (and if so, can you [edit] the question to include only a [mcve])?

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you take a look again? I now only get `Application object must be callable`.

Comment: For this error would be nice to show what `socket_` actually is, because it is what should be callable and it is far from standard "app/application".

Comment: It is a flask SocketIO instance, I will try to provide a minimal reproducible example when I can.

Comment: @DavidMaze @SUTerliakov I've edited my question, also If I remove the nginx container the result is the same, If I go to `mydomain.com:15432` I can access the pgadmin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the host name issue, I had to remove all the network directives in `docker-compose.yml` and change the gunicorn command to use eventlet worker class and point to `app` not `socket_`.

```
services:
    web:
        command: gunicorn wsgi:app --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --reload
```

I have also changed the `nginx.conf` with the example on gunicorn docs.

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # 'use epoll;' to enable for Linux 2.6+
  # 'use kqueue;' to enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # for UNIX domain socket setups
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for a TCP configuration
    # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    # if no Host match, close the connection to prevent host spoofing
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
  }

  server {
    # use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
    # use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /path/to/app/current/public;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
  }
}
```